# The Url where we type in address bar must not be accepted

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-3.0

Hello All I need all your help badly. We have made a role,ID based application in asp.net(C#) where the menu appear as per his roles. This is fine now the users are trying to directly type the link in address bars and using them. Cant restrict them in page loads and sessions as this is a production site which is already slow. So my intension is to show the url in encrypted format which expires in certain time where the user cant copy and paste it. Is there any possible way...

Comment: Please help me I need it in urgency

Comment: Yeah. Your approach is broken. Fix the slow code so you can do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for user role in page_load event and if the user does not have permission then redirect him to a page showing permission denied.
Please provide code if you need further help.

Answer (score 1):

> Cant restrict them in page loads and sessions as this is a production site which 
>   is already slow.

Fix that crappy code and / or add more servers. Because this is the ONLY way it makes sense to do it. Anything else is the type of security that gets broken into and then you run around blaming the world for being unfair.

> So my intension is to show the url in encrypted format which expires in certain 
>   time where the user cant copy and paste it.

? So the menu has an encrypted URL that is only valid like for half a second? What if the user browses the source code of the page? He can see all the source there.

This is not security, it is hogwash. Sorry to be blunt, but this is not going to work and you are making a bad job here.

Checking this in page load will take less than a millisecond (assuming you cache roles in the session). WAY less.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.... you've painted yourself into a corner here.

**Short answer:**

No, there's no clean way to do this and whatever type of 'special' url implementation you create will be open to abuse/spoofing and still require you to add code anyway.

**Long answer:**

I can't see any viable solution other than injecting some code into `Page_Load`.

I take it you're not using WIF/Claims-based security, just some bespoke written user login, database store based code? So your best approach (**at this point**) is to make a simple class in `App_Code`:  When the user logs in, load their permissions into something like a `DataTable` and store that in a session variable. That way you can avoid doing database requests every time the page loads/posts back, this'll probably speed your site up a bit too.

Build a non-static method in a class that is to be used on `Page_Load`, where this will get the URL (or page id) being accessed, then check that against the session stored `DataTable`. If that check fails redirect them to an access denied page.

Building the class foundation is key, don't attempt to shortcut and copy-paste chunks of code into each page. With the 'security' class you can standardise your code and reduce testing down to a few simple checks.